# tabindex="-1" not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: modal-dialog, tabindex

tabindex="-1" not working on bootstrap modal.
If I keep pressing the tab key, the focus is going to the background and able to focus on other links.

Can some one help me here.

Answer (score 1):

With tabindex=-1 the element should not be reachable with keyboard. So if you press the tab key, the focus is going to the next focusable element.
Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: My question is if i press the tab key, the focus should be on only modal and it will not go beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Trying Enter role="dialog" and aria-hidden="true" too in the model-fade